# I"m working on my own search engine. How to consume other portals content?

Tags: java, rest, http

I intend to create a new website which will act as something as a centralized search engine for bicycles. The idea is that the visitor can perform a search on my site and then get offers from several other portals out there. Something like swoodoo, skyskanner, etc. for flight but for bikes.

What would be the best approach for querying other portals (using java) if they don't offer a public api? The "best" option I'm working with is to send a hardcoded GET or POST request to each of the portals and then work with their response but that seems very hard to maintain and not a good option at all.

Any hints or reading material you can point me to?

Answer (score 1):

So from my point of view you have two options:

- Query a public API for the need data
- Scape the sites for data

The best option would differently be, if the sites your were interested in had a public API that you could query in order to fetch the information. I doubt that many of the sites have that.

Therefore the second option would be two scape the sites for information that you are interested in. If you choose this option, be aware that every time the sites you scrape changes the HTML structure id, class etc. your scraping functionality might need to be maintained.

So by choosing this option, be ware that you need to continuously maintain your scraping program!

Here is a link that explains what scraping is and how it can could be done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsmxMLmroyQ

This is not Java specific, but you would be able to map it to Java.